# Get Json value from controller to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a JS function:

```
$(document).on('click', '#submitForm', function (e) {
var fileName = $('#fileName').val();
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Calculation/FileExist',
    data: { 'fileName': fileName },
    dataType: 'bool',
    success: function (result) {
        if (result.returnvalue) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert(result.returnvalue);
            alert("The filename already exists. Please choose another one");
        }
        else {
            alert("The file doesn't exist");
        }
    }
});
});
```

My action:

```
    public ActionResult FileExist(string fileName)
    {
        bool result = true;
        string path = Server.MapPath(TempPath) + fileName + ".xlsx"; //Path for the file
        string[] Files = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath(TempPath));
        for (int i = 0; i < Files.Length; i++)
        {
            if (path == Files[i])
            {
                //The filename already exists
                result = false;
            }
        }
        return Json(new { returnvalue = result });
    }
```

What am I doing wrong here? I'm trying to get the bool value from FileExist method, and if it's true stop the form from submitting (e.preventDefault)

Comment: what's happening? open browser developer console, do you get any response? are there any js errors? please provide more info.

Comment: Just change your dataType or delete the property completely and then compare the result with "true" or e.g.

Comment: ajax is asynchronous call, so even before getting boolean from server your page is submitting. so set async:false in jquery ajax option to behave like synchronous call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, specify `dataType: 'json'` in your jquery ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    // <...>
    dataType: 'json'
    // <...>
});
```

**If you would like to use `HTTP GET`:**

```
public ActionResult FileExist(string fileName) 
{
    // <...>
    return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**You can use `HTTP POST` method:**

```
[HttpPost] // Add this attribute.
public ActionResult FileExist(string fileName) 
{ 
    // <...>
    return Json(model);
}
```

Comment: OP uses `POST` request. It it not necessary to use JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet for POST until, if you are going to use it for GET

Answer (score 2):

There is no `dataType: 'bool'`. Please use `dataType:'json'` `dataType:'text'` to send the boolean values

In your case, it should be `dataType:'json'`

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Calculation/FileExist',
    data: { 'fileName': fileName },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (result) {
        if (result.returnvalue) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert(result.returnvalue);
            alert("The filename already exists. Please choose another one");
        }
        else {
            alert("The file doesn't exist");
        }
    }
});
```

Then

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FileExist(string fileName)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On top of your controller method, you have to put this annotation:

```
[HttpPost]
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `[HttpPost]` to your controller,set dataType:'json' and set `async:false` in jquery ajax why do you need POST method. Just use GET method and add `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` in your controller

Answer (score 0):

put `datatype`  as`json` not **bool** ans also add `[HttpPost]` attribute on your action or other way is to put `type:'GET'`

Answer (score 0):

> The available data types in a service call are:
>
> 1. xml
> 2. html
> 3. script
> 4. json
> 5. jsonp

As per your code:

change the dataType to json as you are returning json from the server.

And by default the ActionResult will be using `GET` while in your ajax call you have specified `POST`.

So include `[HttpPost]` at the top of the method.